# JavaScript doesn't run when tab isn't open

Tags: javascript

For some reason, my code doesn't appear to run in the background if the tab's not open.

Here is the code:

```js
num = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
  num = num + 1;
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = num;
}, 10);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Space...</title>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="num">0</span>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

But it is working on a separate game I've made, i.e. it does continue running if the tab's not open.

I've searched the web and Stack Overflow for answers, but I haven't been able to find any. I don't know why this is happening, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i still don't understand the answer.

Comment: What don't you understand about the answer? Per the duplicate link, you'd want to run setInterval in a web worker, and use self.postMessage to tell the main thread something has changed. From what is written there, it works around the setInterval limitation.

Comment: Aha, ok. Thanks, that's a bit clearer.